# Period as a function of n

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

It is evident from Fibonacci sequence mod(3) $$ 1,1,2,0,2,2,1,0,1,1,2,0,...$$ that every fourth term of the Fibonacci sequence is a multiple of $3$.

Similarly for mod(5)  $$1,1,2,3,0,3,3,1,4,0,4,4,3,2,0,2,2,4,1,0,1,1,2,....$$ suggests that every fifth term in the Fibonacci sequence is a multiple of $5$.

It has been shown that every positive integer n divides the terms of the Fibonacci sequence periodically. The period depends on n .

Question: Is it possible to express the period p as a function of n?
For example we have to get p(3)=4 and p(5)=5.

Comment: You can derive an algebraic expression for the Fibonacci sequence. Maybe that would help.

Comment: The algebraic expression makes it more complicated.

Comment: Also related to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/631171/proof-that-fibonacci-sequence-modulo-m-is-periodic?rq=1

Comment: And... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872071/fibonacci-number-that-ends-with-2014-zeros/872077#872077

Comment: Note that expressing   p(n)  as a function of n is a new question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because it explicitly asks about divisibility by any number and not just $3$.

Comment: That is my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to show (with conventional numbering $F_1=1, F_2=1, F_3=2, F_4=3, F_5=5, F_6=8 \dots$) that $F_d|F_{nd}$ for any integer $n$.

The fact that the series recurs modulo any positive integer $r$ is inevitable because there are only finitely many pairs of integers mod $r$, and any pair determines the whole sequence.

I suggest you try to prove this divisibility rule - you might want to try showing $F_d|F_{2d}$ first, as this has some neat features which you might spot if you test the first few examples.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive comment

Comment: My question remains unanswered. Can we express p(n) as a function of n?

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani I don't think it is easy to establish which $F_r$ is the first divisible by $n$ or even by a given prime $p$. The period for given $p$ is $r_p$ where $F_{r_p}$ is the first F_r divisible by $p$. We have $(p, r_p)= (2,3), (3,4), (5,5), (7,8), (11,10), (13,7), (17,9), (19,18),(23,24), (29,14) \dots (89,11) \dots$. Now there are some patterns to investigate. Aside from $5$ the period is a factor of $p\pm 1$, and the prime $5$ plays a special part here.

Comment: I am still working on it. Is 5 the only integer for which p(n)=n? For which integers p(n)<n, and many  other questions.

Comment: Is $F_d|F_{2d}$ true if d is not prime?

Comment: @MohammadRiazi-Kermani Yes: F_{2d}=F_dL_d$ where $L_d$ is the related Lucas number. I think you would do well to do some reading about Fibonacci Numbers, and also some testing for yourself as to what patterns you can see. (I sometimes use a spreadsheet for such purposes, as it will tabulate values quite efficiently). I found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511379/divisibility-of-fibonacci-numbers, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime all of which have comments relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks again. I will read more about Fibonacci Numbers and see if  can figure out a formula for p(n).